# $\overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \ \mid \ n \}} \cap \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} \} } = 0$, but their sum is dense

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Regarding this question:[Show that the intersection of $\overline{\text{span }\{e_{2n}\}}$ and $\overline{\text{span }\{e_{2n}+\frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1}\}}$ is zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458500/show-that-the-intersection-of-overline-textspan-e-2n-and-overline).

The above has an accepted answer, but there is no proof of the result from the title. I am looking for a proof for that result and also that
$$\overline{\overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \ \mid \ n \}} + \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} \} }} = H. $$
I have not been able to do it myself.

For the first part, I have started by picking $x \in \overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \}} \cap \overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1} e_{2n+1} \}} .$

Then, we know that $$x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x, e_n \rangle e_n. $$
Moreover, there is a sequence $(x_k)_{k}$ with $x_k \in \mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \}$ for every $k$ and such that $x_k \to x$.
Using the same reasoning, there is a sequence $(y_k)_k$ with $y_k \in \mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1} e_{2n+1} \}$ and such that $y_k \to x$. However, I do not know how to proceed from here.

I do not know how to start the second part either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some basic properties of orthogonal sequences. First verify that $(e_{2n}+\frac  1 {n+1} e_{2n+1})$ is an orthogonal sequence.

If  $(f_n)$ is an orthogonal sequence then  any vector in the closed subspace spanned by this sequence can be written as a sum $\sum a_n x_n$.

Suppose $x$ belongs to the intersection of the closed subspace spanned by the sequences $(e_{2n})$ and $(e_{2n}+\frac  1 {n+1} e_{2n+1})$. Then $x=\sum a_n e_{2n}$ and $x=\sum b_n (e_{2n}+\frac  1 {n+1} e_{2n+1})$. This gives $\sum (a_n-b_n)e_{2n}=\sum b_n \frac  1 {n+1} e_{2n+1}$. This implies that $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$ and $b_n=0$ for al $n$. Hence $x=0$.

To show that the sum of the two spaces is dense it is enough to show that if vector $x$ is orthogonnal to the sum then it is $0$. But this is obvious since $x$ must be orthogoanal to $e_{2n}$ as well as $e_{2n+1}$ for every $n$.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. For the first part: for a total orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space, Parseval's identity holds for every element (and $F$ and $G$ are Hilbert spaces). And for the second part, $M^\perp = 0$ if and only if $\mathrm{span}(M)$ is dense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the density of the sum:
The sum contains the ONB vectors $e_k,k\in\mathbb N$, thus it also contains their finite linear combinations. These altogether constitute a dense subspace of $H$.

Regarding that the subspaces intersect trivially:
This is the subject of an older question which got
[a fresh answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3933590/316749) there.