# $\overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \ \mid \ n \}} + \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} \} }$ is dense but not the entire space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Regarding my previous question: [$\overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \ \mid \ n \}} \cap \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} \} } = 0$, but their sum is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922874/overline-mathrmspan-e-2n-mid-n-cap-overline-mathrmspan).

In the context of the above question: $\mathcal{H}$ is a separable Hilbert space, with a total orthonormal set $\{e_n \}_n$. I have able to prove that $$\overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \ \mid \ n \}} \cap \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} \} } $$ is an internal direct sum and that $$\overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \ \mid \ n \}} + \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} \} } $$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$. However, I would now like to prove that $$\overline{\mathrm{span} \{e_{2n} \ \mid \ n \}} + \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} \} } \neq \mathcal{H}. $$

I have tried to do so by considering the sequence $$x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} = \left( e_{2n} + \frac{1}{n+1}e_{2n+1} \right) - e_{2n},$$ and at its sequence of partial sums $$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i. $$

The sequence $(s_n)_n$ does converge in $\mathcal{H}$ as, the sequence $(1/n)_n$ is an element of $\ell^2$. However, is its limit in the direct sum from above?

Comment: Yes, that sequence converges in norm to zero because $\|e_{2n+1}\|=1$ for all $n$, and zero is of course in both spans in question. You might suppose for a contradiction that the sum of span closures equals $H=\overline{\text{span}(e_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}}$ (where we note that $(e_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Schuader basis for the separable $H$). In particular, every element of $H$ can be expressed uniquely in the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}e_{n}$ and you might be able to use this uniqueness to your advantage.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a mistake in writing the exact sequence (I was referring to the sequence of partial sums of $x_n$). I will edit now.

Comment: @JWP_HTX I think I managed to solve it using your comment, but I used the coefficients in a different space. Let $s = \sum_n x_n$ and suppose that $s$ in that direct sum, i.e. $s = f \oplus g$. Since $\langle s, e_{2n} \rangle = 0$, we must have that $f = 0$, and so $s$ is an element in the second term of the direct sum. However, as that subspace it itself a Hilbert space, it follows that $s = \sum_{n} \alpha_n (e_{2n} + e_{2n+1}/(n+1)$ for some $\alpha_n$, and this clearly leads to a contradiction by the uniqueness of coefficients. Is this a correct argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track: No, the limit is not contained in the direct sum. Which proves the question claim.

The proof depends on a fact in Banach space theory:
Let $B$ be a Banach space and consider closed subspaces $X,Z\subset B$. If $B$ is *algebraically isomorphic* to the direct sum $X\oplus Z$, then the *isomorphism is also topological*, i.e., an isomorphism of Banach spaces.
This is implied by the Inverse mapping theorem which states "The inverse of a continuous linear bijection between Banach spaces is continuous." (being a corollary to the Open mapping theorem).
Furthermore, the projectors onto the subspaces are then *continuous* operators on $B$.

Generalising your choice of $(s_n)$, let $\lambda\in\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ satisfy $\lambda_{2n+1}\neq 0\,$ for infinitely many $n$, but $\lambda_{2n}=0$ for all $n$.
This gives
$$v\:=\:\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lambda_{2n+1}e_{2n+1}\in\mathcal{H}$$
and it is shown, after appropriate choice of $\lambda$, that $v\notin F+G\,$ where $F,G$ denote the closed subspaces in question.
Look at the partial sums
$$\begin{align}v_N & \:=\:\sum_{n=0}^N\lambda_{2n+1}e_{2n+1}\:=\:
\sum_{n=0}^N\lambda_{2n+1}\big[(n+1)\big(e_{2n}+\tfrac1{n+1}e_{2n+1}\big)
 -(n+1)e_{2n}\big]\\[1ex]
 & \:=\:\sum_{n=0}^N\lambda_{2n+1}\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}\; \frac{e_{2n}+\tfrac1{n+1}e_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1+\frac1{(n+1)^2}}}
 \quad-\quad\sum_{n=0}^N\,(n+1)\lambda_{2n+1}\,e_{2n}\end{align}$$
which are finite linear combinations, thus certainly $v_N\in F+G$.
It is [shown in another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3458500/316749) that $F\cap G=\{0\}$, so that we really deal with a direct sum  decomposition $F\oplus G$ here. Then the splitting in the last formula line into $F$- and $G$-components is uniquely determined, and these components are the images under the two projections onto $F$ and $G$ of $v_N$.

If $F\oplus G$ were all of $\mathcal H$, then the projections are continuous by the above fact, and the convergence $v_N\rightarrow v$ implies convergence in $F$ and $G$ separately.
Now many possible choices for $\lambda\in\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ carry on sabotage of convergence in $F$ and $G$. Your choice made in the question  is one of them since the second summand then becomes $\sum_{n=0}^N e_{2n}\,$.
This proves $F\oplus G\not= \mathcal H.\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: Could you please explain why the convergence of $v_N$ implies the separate convergence of each sum from above?

Comment: Does the following more or less similar argument work? That is, suppose that $s = \lim_n s_n$ is in the direct sum. Then, $s = a \oplus b$. We know that $a = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e_{2n}$ and $b = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n (e_{2n} + e_{2n+1}/(n+1))$ and both of these sequences converge. Equating the coefficients with the expansion of $s$ in the orthonormal basis of $H$, we must have that $b_n = 1$ and $a_n = -1$. However, these sequences are not in $\ell^2$, so we get a contradiction.

Comment: A hasty reply (esp. to your first comment) involves the "Inverse mapping thm", which states: The inverse of a continuous linear bijection between Banach spaces is continuous. If you have two subspaces which intersect trivially & which add up to the whole space [which is *not* the case here], then the injection of the (external) direct sum is continuous & bijective. Thus its inverse is continuous, and the inverse is given by the pair of projectors onto the two subspaces.